# How to add a VSTO add-in to inclusion list with registry keys?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have a VSTO add-in that I want to install without promting the user. This add-in is not installed in Program Files folder.
For now I have a solution described in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398239.aspx
It is easy to use and works perfectly. The problem is, this function was removed from VSTO runtime in version 10.0 (it worked in VSTO runtime 9.0).

Time passed, and now most of my users use Windows 10 and don't have .NET Framework 3.5 preinstalled. I could force them to install it, but I thought that mabe moving forward would be a better solution. So, I would like to add an add-in to inclusion list but without using the function I mentioned above. I guess the only way is to put proper registry keys in place by myself.

So the question is, which registry keys should I add or change to make it work?

Comment: I got installation w/o prompting to work by making my own installer in Python.

There are some registry keys you have to create to register the VSTO per office application you want the add-in to run in.

I found the key part to avoiding the install prompt is installing the cert the VSTO is signed with to the Trusted Publishers and Trusted Root cert paths.

Answer (score -1):

The UserInclusionList classes have been moved to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0.dll according to
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/vsto/assemblies-in-the-visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime.md

But you indeed need .NET Fx 3.5 for this to function, so add it to the registry yourself instead of using the classes.

The inclusion list is skipped if you install your application in the program files folder (as a result of the fact that the .msi already needs elevated mode to be able to install in the Program Files folders) but again, your scenario is that you'll be outside the Program Files folders so my best guess is that you need to update the registry entries using your own installation.

Comment: This answer is not useful, as it does not describe how to add the registry entries "using your own installation".

Comment: There is no way to add a generic answer to "using your own installation" as with VSTO everyone uses their own choice of installer. Addin registry items can easily be found by Binggoogling as it is a common procedure. If @Peter you are looking for the -format- of the Inclusion list (that was not asked for in the OP question) basic searching the Internet also provides you quickly with an answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-configure-inclusion-list-security?view=vs-2022